# NSButton Title is not visible while CALayer is set to the NSButton Layer in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

[image]I have struck with NSButton Title visibility. What I have done is, I have taken CALayer and arrange background color, corner radius and border width for that layer. Finally this layer is set to the NSButton Layer But after doing this Title of the NSButton is not visible. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

Here my code, What I have tried.

```
 var wordButton = new NSButton(new CGRect(20, 0, tableColumn.Width - 70, 30));

 CALayer layer = new CALayer();

 layer.CornerRadius = 5f;

 layer.BorderWidth = 1f;

 layer.BackgroundColor = NSColor.FromRgba(0.70f, 0.87f, 0.86f, 1.0f).CGColor;

 wordButton.WantsLayer = true;

 wordButton.Layer = layer;

 wordButton.Title = "Test";

 wordButton.SetButtonType(NSButtonType.MomentaryPushIn);

 wordButton.BezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.SmallSquare;
```

Comment: Just to confirm that this is not a bug in Xamarin, I was able to convert this to Swift and the same behaviour was shown.

Answer (score 2):

Customize the existing layer:

```
wordButton.WantsLayer = true;

//wordButton.Layer = layer;
wordButton.Layer.CornerRadius = 5f;
wordButton.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;
wordButton.Layer.BackgroundColor = NSColor.FromRgba (0.70f, 0.87f, 0.86f, 1.0f).CGColor;
```

But this will but you background behind the default button UI.

NSButton is not designed to be customized this way. 
If you do want a custom background you should subclass NSButton override drawrect and draw the label yourself

Comment: This answer is correct. Many Cocoa controls will not respond as you'd desire when you add layer drawing, and you get to do some heavy lifting.